# GE Dishwasher - Control Pad Buttons Won't Respond (gld5660v00ss)

Tags: kitchens, appliances, dishwasher

I have a GE gld5660v00ss Dishwasher that no longer responds. The "Normal Wash" and "Heated Dry" buttons are lit, but no other buttons respond. The Start button does nothing, and none of the other buttons light up when pressed.

The door itself latches, and still beeps when latched but that's it.

Is it time for a new dish washer?

Looks like all the replaceable electronic components are $100+ and might not fix the problem.

I thought maybe the dishwasher was locked, and tried holding down the "Heated Dry" button for 3 seconds, but that was not the case.

Help!

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting it from mains power (either by unplugging it if you can or by turning the breaker for the circuit it is on off) and then plugging it back in/turning the breaker back on after 15s?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, already tried that.

Comment: have you checked the cable between the buttons assembly and the rest of the machine?

Comment: @scorpdaddy Yes, just checked all cables, including removing and ensuring each one is securely attached.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your control board is failing, considering that unpowering and repowering the unit is not getting it out of the bad state -- replacing it should fix it.